# Remote code execution in ruby on rails application via string interpolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have come across a blog https://buer.haus/2017/03/13/airbnb-ruby-on-rails-string-interpolation-led-to-remote-code-execution/ which explains Remote code execution in ruby application due to usage of string interpolation.

I completely understand the string interpolation concept. However I don't know how it could lead to remote code execution.

Can someone please explain the remote code execution via string interpolation concept with a sample set of code ?

Comment: There is an example provided in the blog post -- they execute a shell command.

Comment: The stuff inside `#{...}` in Ruby string interpolation can be any Ruby expression, not just variables and such. So, as in the example, you can say `"#{%x[ls]}"` to execute `ls` through the shell.

Comment: Please do not link to external resources without providing the necessary context directly in your post. Links die, websites go away, etc. If there is a specific explanation of string interpolation leading to remote code execution that is the basis of your question then the entirety of that explanation must be included in your question.